# Wx frame closes automatically

Tags: wxpython

When the following code is run, the frame appears quickly and closes automatically. OS: Windows 10, Python3.6
Can someone help me to understand why this happens?

```
import sys, random, string, base64,time, calendar, io, threading, wx

try:
    #Python 2.7
    import thread
except ImportError:
    #python 3.xx
    import _thread as thread

class gameUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self._rows = 0
        self._columns = 0
        self._user = None
        app = wx.App()
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Button Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Press Me")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, event):
        """
        This method is fired when its corresponding button is pressed
        """
        print ("Button pressed!")

def main():
    # try:
        # app = wx.App()
        # frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Simple application')
        # frame.Show()
        # time.sleep(10)
        # app.MainLoop()
    try:
        frame = gameUI()
        frame.Show()
        time.sleep(10)
        app.MainLoop()
    finally:
        del app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

A wx.App should be created first before creating any windows.
A try with a finally to delete app is not required, app will be deleted by the garbage collector when all windows are closed.
time has not been imported so this would error, but you don't really want to have to wait 10 seconds for the window to become responsive, better to remove it.

```
import wx


class gameUI(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        self._rows = 0
        self._columns = 0
        self._user = None
#         app = wx.App() dont create app here
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Button Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Press Me")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)

    def onButton(self, event):
        """
        This method is fired when its corresponding button is pressed
        """
        print ("Button pressed!")


def main():

#     try:
    app = wx.App()
    frame = gameUI()
    frame.Show()
#     time.sleep(10)
    app.MainLoop()


#     finally:
#         del app not required
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The import of time module was there but I missed to paste here. Also the reason I kept 10 sec is to see the frame appears for sometime otherwise it closes so quickly

Answer (score 0):

You still have issues in there.

- The Gui won't show up until the `MainLoop` starts, so the `sleep` command is in the wrong place and if you put it after the `MainLoop`, it won't activate until the Gui returns on close i.e. `MainLoop` terminates.
- The definition of `wx.App` is still not in the usual place and where it 
  is, it would still have to be declared as `self.app` and still have to be referred to as `frame.app`.
- As you are probably new to wxpython, you are not using `sizers` for widget positioning, so you must give each widget at least a position, if not a size (they will attempt to size themselves).

Try the code below and note the differences.

```
import sys, random, string, base64,time, calendar, io, threading, wx

try:
    #Python 2.7
    import thread
except ImportError:
    #python 3.xx
    import _thread as thread

class gameUI(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,title):
        self._rows = 0
        self._columns = 0
        self._user = None
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Button Tutorial")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Press Me", pos=(20,20), size=(80,25))
        quit = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Quit", pos=(20,50), size=(80,25))
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButton)
        quit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onQuit)

    def onButton(self, event):
        """
        This method is fired when its corresponding button is pressed
        """
        print ("Button pressed!")

    def onQuit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

def main():
    try:
        app = wx.App()
        frame = gameUI(None, title='Simple application')
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
    finally:
        del app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the code doesn't show the error that you stated. When it executes, the frame appears but it doesn't show button and waits for 10 sec and closes by itself

Comment: @Mohanasundaram Then the code you posted and the code you are running are different. Not the best scenario ;)

Comment: I have now pasted the exact code that I use to run. Can you pls comment now?

Comment: Yes it works and thanks for the code and information

Comment: You are welcome. Should you care to, you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey tick beside the answer or indeed accept the answer given by `Yoriz` as it's pretty much the same answer.